# How to set appropriate zoom level for GoogleMap Api3 in GWT

Tags: google-maps, gwt, google-maps-api-3, zooming

I am using GWT2.5 and GoogleMap Api3.

I have 2 scenarios:
1. I am having the center latlng for the map and few markers on it.
2. Any county and few markers on it.

So, the map should be appropriately zoomed to fit the markers.

Is there a way to automatically detect the zoom level?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google maps doesn't have a "`fitAllMarkers`" function / method, but you should be able to achieve this reasonably simply using the `fitBounds` method.

I have **not** tested the following code, but something like this should work:

```
// A list of all your markers.
List<Marker> markers;

// Get the current bounds of your map.
LatLngBounds latLngBounds = googleMap.getBounds();

for(Marker marker : markers) {
  // Extend the bounds of your map to fit the position (LatLng) of each marker.
  latLngBounds.extend(marker.getPosition()); 
}

// This may not be needed - test it.
// Tell the map to zoom to fit the bounds that you defined for your markers.
googleMap.fitBounds(latLngBounds);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are a few examples with using the GWT maps v3 api. I think I cover all your questions in those examples.

https://github.com/branflake2267/GWT-Maps-V3-Api/tree/master/gwt-maps-showcase/src/main/java/com/google/gwt/maps/testing/client/maps - example maps

https://github.com/branflake2267/GWT-Maps-V3-Api - api home

Comment: Thanks for the wide variety of examples. But i couldnt find which one suits for me.